# Suggested Edit Review - specific case

Tags: discussion, support

I am looking at this suggested edit:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1340746 .

I voted to reject this edit, with an additional comment of suggestions that improve an answer should be offered as a comment in this case. However, I see 3 people had already rejected the edit, and my rejection doesn't even show up in the list there. Should I be taking the time to comment on individual edits? Would the user see my rejection or see:

> This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive
>   improvements addressing multiple issues in the post
>   ?

Comment: A comment with suggestions for improvements is great.

Answer (score 1):

If you take the time to add a custom reject message, that shows up in the history of the suggested edit.

However, people doing less-than-good edits are perhaps also less likely to follow up on the results of their proposed edits. If he isn't specifically looking for it, the will not see your message.

I still add some specific messages, especially if I see a user who is doing something systematically wrong, like searching for a specific spelling error and fixing that error *only*. In that case there will possibly be an edit ban for the user, making him (hopefully) review his results.

In your specific case, when the edit was rejected anyway, I wouldn't do anything more about that. There are lots of other reviews to put your time on.

Comment: True, to be quick enough (so that your review will go through before 3 others do it) it's better to store possible comments in one place then just copy&paste the proper comment.

Comment: As clarification, it was after I started editing that I found out it was rejected. My original question for meta was actually going to be different - what to do about edits that "improve" code? For the most part I reject and indicate that it should be added as a comment or as another answer.